# ng2-chart: Smallest values in bar chart is invisible

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-charts

Dataset has value 10 and 50000, it can not display bar with value 10 in column 2006 of chart, because it smallest with scale of chart. Could anyone help me to show it?

```
public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: { //you're missing this
      yAxes: [{
         scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Frequency Rate'
         },
         ticks: { // and this
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
             return value/1000 + 'k';
          }
        }
      }]
   }
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    
    { data: [6500, 5900, 8000, 8100, 5600, 5500, 4000], label: 'Series A' },
    { data: [10, 4800, 4000, 1900, 8600, 2700, 50000], label: 'Series B' }
  ];
```

[You can see Chart in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKFau.png)

You can see full code here:
[a link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-kcqbak?file=src/app/app.component.ts)!

Answer (score 1):

`10 is 0.02% of 50000`

In the image you shared the 50 000 column is 210px high and

`0.02% of 210 is 0.042 px`

So it is less than a pixel in height which is why it is not rendering in the column.